# Play Mailer Service not able to send email

Tags: java, email, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am having problem in sending email using play framework [mailer](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) plugin. I tried turning on the secure setting on the Gmail account as per suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189680/not-able-to-send-emails-from-play-mailer-plugin) but still it is not able to send my email.

My Setting in `application.conf`:

```
play.mailer {
  host="smtp.gmail.com"
  port=587
  ssl=yes
  tls=no
  user="l************ay@gmail.com"
  password="****************"
  debug=yes
  timeout=60
  connectiontimeout=60
  mock=no
}
```

I tried connecting with other ports as well like [`465`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server) as its suggested in some other answers of same problem. My code for sending email is something like this:

```
String cid = "1234";
Email email = new Email();
email.setSubject("Verify Account Please");
email.setFrom("l************ay@gmail.com");
email.addTo("l************ay@gmail.com");

email.setBodyHtml("<html><body><p>An <b>html</b> message with cid <img src=\"cid:" + cid + "\"></p></body></html>");
mailerClient.send(email);
```

But I am still getting following exception:

[image]

Following is the error i am getting:

`org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465`

My Play Framework version is 2.5

Comment: Please paste the error message as text and not an image.

Comment: `587` is the TSL port and you have `tsl=no`. The correct port when using `SSL` is 465. See [this page from Google help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en).

Comment: @marcospereia I tried with 465 for ssl=yes and tsl=no and the error was still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out the way how to resolve it. Problem was not my code but it was my antivirus which is avast Antivirus. My antivirus protection was blocking all the calls of smtp going out. I disabled it and everything was working fine. I used gmail over TLS emails. My final configuration in `application.conf` is:

```
play.mailer {
  host = "smtp.gmail.com"
  port = 587
  ssl = no
  tls = yes
  user = "*********@gmail.com"
  password = "**********"
  debug = no
}
```

i also had a [discussion](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/issues/115) on [play-mailer](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/) github forum and one of the developer (i presume) was helpful and frequent. I also posted my code over there. So anyone having trouble may get the help as well :).